# SQL error - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I am trying to create some tables in a database with java (jdbc).
The "code" underneath is just two strings, each containing an SQL CREATE TABLE update, one for the table "store_sales" and one for the table "store_returns"
I get
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot add foreign key constraint

that happens when I try to make store_returns.sr_ticket_number a foreign key referencing store_sales.ss_ticket_number in the last line of the "code"

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store_sales ("
        + "ss_sold_date_sk int,"
        + "ss_sold_time_sk int,"
        + "ss_item_sk int not null,"
        + "ss_customer_sk int,"
        + "ss_cdemo_sk int,"
        + "ss_hdemo_sk int,"
        + "ss_addr_sk int,"
        + "ss_store_sk int,"
        + "ss_promo_sk int,"
        + "ss_ticket_number int not null,"
        + "primary key (ss_item_sk,ss_ticket_number),"
        + "foreign key (ss_sold_date_sk) references date_dim (d_date_sk),"
        + "foreign key (ss_sold_time_sk) references time_dim (t_time_sk),"
        + "foreign key (ss_item_sk) references item (i_item_sk),"
        + "foreign key (ss_customer_sk) references customer (c_customer_sk),"
        + "foreign key (ss_cdemo_sk) references customer_demographics (cd_demo_sk),"
        + "foreign key (ss_hdemo_sk) references household_demographics (hd_demo_sk),"
        + "foreign key (ss_addr_sk) references customer_address (ca_address_sk),"
        + "foreign key (ss_store_sk) references store (s_store_sk),"
        + "foreign key (ss_promo_sk) references promotion (p_promo_sk)"
        + ")"

        ,

        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store_returns ("
        + "sr_return_date_sk int,"
        + "sr_return_time_sk int,"
        + "sr_item_sk int not null,"
        + "sr_customer_sk int,"
        + "sr_cdemo_sk int,"
        + "sr_hdemo_sk int,"
        + "sr_addr_sk int,"
        + "sr_store_sk int,"
        + "sr_reason_sk int,"
        + "sr_ticket_number int not null,"
        + "primary key (sr_item_sk,sr_ticket_number),"
        + "foreign key (sr_return_date_sk) references date_dim (d_date_sk),"
        + "foreign key (sr_return_time_sk) references time_dim (t_time_sk),"
        + "foreign key (sr_item_sk) references item (i_item_sk),"
        + "foreign key (sr_customer_sk) references customer (c_customer_sk),"
        + "foreign key (sr_cdemo_sk) references customer_demographics (cd_demo_sk),"
        + "foreign key (sr_hdemo_sk) references household_demographics (hd_demo_sk),"
        + "foreign key (sr_addr_sk) references customer_address (ca_address_sk),"
        + "foreign key (sr_store_sk) references store (s_store_sk),"
        + "foreign key (sr_reason_sk) references reason (r_reason_sk),"
        + "foreign key (sr_ticket_number) references store_sales (ss_ticket_number)"
        + ")"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add a foreign key constraint to a part of a combined foreign key like (ss_item_sk,ss_ticket_number) in store_sales. For a foreign key constraint you have to address all parts of the primary key of the referenced table.

Something like

```
foreign key (sr_item_sk, sr_ticket_number) references store_sales (ss_item_sk,ss_ticket_number)
```

should work

Comment: Thanks a million for the super-sonic response! Sorry, I'm a newbie here and I cannot upvote (I need 15 reputation)