# Creating Foreign Key in SQL is being deemed incompatible, don't know why

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am trying to add a foreign key to link my two tables together. They already have primary keys and I keep getting this error in response:

> ERROR 3780 (HY000): Referencing column 'empid' and referenced column
>   'empid' in foreign key constraint 'pqaemployeeaddress_ibfk_1' are
>   incompatible.

My parent table is this

[image: My parent table is this!]

My child table is this

[image: My child table is this!]

Both the primary keys are unsigned. I am unsure why they are incompatible and am unsure how to link my tables. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Can you add the definitions (column names and data types) of the two tables to the question as well as what database you are using and the command you are running to create the foreign key?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL error - Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486255/sql-error-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: Thank you so much, I figured the problem out. My child table had a column name which I labelled "int" - but forgot to include "int unsigned" so it wouldn't link. 

Thank you all for your super fast responses!

Comment: Makes sense.  You should accept your answer so viewers know the issue is resolved.

Comment: @Chris94 I can only accept my answer in two days. I tried :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I solved my own problem, but I figured I should post the answer.

When making one of my columns, I labelled it as "int" but not "int unsigned" which turned out to be the problem.

So, once I entered this into MySQL:

```
mysql> alter table pqaemployeeaddress modify column empid int unsigned;
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.97 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

It fixed it, so then I was able to add my foreign key.

```
mysql> alter table pqaemployeeaddress add foreign key (empid) references pqaemployeelist(empid);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (1.29 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Personally, fun way to check is to then DESCRIBE your table and you can see what types you have assigned it. 
[Image of Describe key word!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bRJP.png)